# Destructor called at the time of getrefcount in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand classes along with `getrefcount()` in Python. When I tried to call `getrefcount()`, class' destructor was called. Below is the code.

```py
import sys
import time
class a:
    def __del__(self):
            print('getting rid of something')
            del self

def f():
    time.sleep(2)
    return 'something'

b = a()
b = f()
```

output -> getting rid of something

sys.refcount(b)
output -> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'refcount'. Did you mean: 'getrefcount'?

sys.getrefcount(b)
output -> getting rid of something
3

```
on the call of `sys.getrefcount(b)` it should not return getting rid of something.
```

Comment: For me, "getting rid of..." is printed just once. What happens if you add `self` to the print, does it `__del__` the same instance twice? Do you do this in an interactive session?

Comment: which Python version do you have?  In 3.10 in ipython shell I see `getting rid of something` just once and `sys.getrefcount(b)` returns `6`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like the best example for learning about classes or getrefcount...

- As others have pointed out, the code you've posted prints out "getting rid of something" only once; perhaps you've simplified it too far while getting it ready to post?
- You're using the `getrefcount` method on the return value from the function, but that's the string `'something'`, not an instance of your class.
- The `getrefcount` function isn't really useful for strings and other [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable) objects, particularly where they're literals in the code (rather than calculated).
- As a side-note, in Python, the `__del__` method is rarely needed; things either get cleaned up automatically, or they should be cleaned up in another method (such as `close` or `__exit__`). Most classes don't have a `__del__` method at all, and writing one correctly is somewhat of an advanced topic.